# Php connection with mssql via odbc, wrong encoding

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I have created mssql connection in php via odbc correctly. I can Insert some data into database but if I want to send some special characters it displayed bad way. I have set UTF-8 charset in my website and UTF-8 file encoding. When i try Insert data from the command line using isql command it works. I've tried already all conversion method but its no effects.

Comment: I don't sure. How can I use this function with odbc? Mysqli is specified only for MySQL but not SQL server.

Comment: Please prodive code for connection

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = 'admin';
$password = 'pass123';
$dsn = 'mydsn';

$connection = odbc_connect($dsn, $user, $password);

if ($connection) {


$data_array = array(
    "string" => "ąĄę12",
);
$sql = "INSERT INTO Table (column_1) VALUES ('".$data_array['string']."')";

$res = odbc_exec($connection, $sql);

if (!$res) {
    error_log("Insert failed");
}

 odbc_close($connection);
}
else {
    die("Connection could not be established.");
}
```

Comment: Is this your solution?  Or should this be part of your question?